# Unable to run a python script

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-22.04

I'm new to python+linux and somewhat stuck. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, created this simplistic script:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

def on_key_event(e):
    if e.name == '1':
        pyautogui.press('h')
        pyautogui.press('k')
keyboard.hook(on_key_event)

#should keep running untill I press "Esc"
keyboard.wait('esc')
keyboard.unhook_all()
```

when i'm trying to run it with `python3 test.py` i'm getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onetwothree/work/sandbox/PY/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    keyboard.hook(on_key_event)
  File "/home/onetwothree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 461, in hook
    append(callback)
  File "/home/onetwothree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 67, in add_handler
    self.start_if_necessary()
  File "/home/onetwothree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 35, in start_if_necessary
    self.init()
  File "/home/naww/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 196, in init
    _os_keyboard.init()
  File "/home/onetwothree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 113, in init
    build_device()
  File "/home/onetwothree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 109, in build_device
    ensure_root()
  File "/home/onetwothree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 174, in ensure_root
    raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.
```

when i'm trying to run it with sudo i'm getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onetwothree/work/sandbox/PY/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few possible solutions here to solve your issue.

**The most obvious**

You most likely installed `pyautogui` using the following command.

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```

The user it's installed under is NOT root ..  You need to run:

```
sudo pip3 install pyautogui
```

That will install under `root` user then:

```
sudo python3 test.py
```

Should run properly.

**Alternatively**

You can use [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) which does not require root privileges to be imported.

Comment: thanks, it works, and thanks x2 for pynput suggestion, it's easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You've likely installed `pyautogui` for your user and not root. So, the package does exist when you run Python normally, but not when you run it via `sudo`. Running Python with `sudo` will look in a different location for its packages compared to when running as a normal user.

The easiest way to fix this would be to run pip with sudo, so it installs the package for the root user:

`sudo pip3 install pyautogui`